# Using adodb-mssqlnative.inc.php with a timeout for update without any result

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sql-update, adodb, sqlsrv

I am using php5.4.38 with Apache2.2.29 on a windows server 2008 with MSSQL as Database with UTF8 fields for chinese language.

I am using adodb and the affected driver is adodb-mssqlnative.inc.php in adodb/drivers folder. It seems that using a timeout for the connection-id for an update query, the update is not writing into database. I just build an own function to show what I am doing:

```
function sql_own_query($connection_id, $sql, $params) {
    $options=array('QueryTimeout' => 90);
    if (substr($sql, 0, 6) != 'select') {
        $options = array();
    }
    if (!empty($options)) {
        $result = sqlsrv_query($connection_id, $sql, $params, $options);
    } else {
        $result = sqlsrv_query($connection_id, $sql, $params);
    }
    return $result;
}

// returns query ID if successful, otherwise false
function _query($sql,$inputarr) {
    $this->_errorMsg = false;
    if (is_array($inputarr)) {
        $rez = $this->sql_own_query($this->_connectionID,$sql,$inputarr);
        //$rez = sqlsrv_query($this->_connectionID,$sql,$inputarr);
    } else if (is_array($sql)) {
        $rez = $this->sql_own_query($this->_connectionID,$sql[1],$inputarr);
        //$rez = sqlsrv_query($this->_connectionID,$sql[1],$inputarr);
    } else {
        $rez = $this->sql_own_query($this->_connectionID,$sql, array());
        //$rez = sqlsrv_query($this->_connectionID,$sql, array());
    }
```

so what I do is: checking if its as select statement and put the $options - parameter into it. If its an update statement it will go through without a timeout parameter.

The problem is, that with QueryTimeout set, the update query will not modify the table. So when I execute:

```
_query('Select ...');//Timeout is set to 90
_query('Update ...');//Timeout is still set
```

the update statement will not have any result. The table is the same as before. The same result will happen when I enlarge the timeout to 300.

I also tested to deactivate the ConnectionPooling as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167(v=sql.105).aspx But without any positive result.

So the question is: Why does an update with timeout will conclude to an empty result. The database is not showing any error, nor php and apache.

PS: Due to the software logic, it is not possible to disable the select statement before. :)

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You have been restart your apache server after change MSSQL configuration ?

Comment: not necessary for that issue. i never changed MSSQL configuration, i just apply settings to adodb for the connection.